# Set Lock Screen Slideshow

Tags: personalization

I like the Auto Changing Lock Screen Wallpaper feature that came to Android 12 and later. Is there any option to enable or installing it on Ubuntu 23.04?
Any type of App/Extension is acceptable

Comment: Like [this?](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2022/05/make-wallpaper-slideshow-ubuntu-2204/) Just use Google in this case...